# Different expected outputs

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So let's say I have an array that is {4 -2 1 2 3 -8 6 7 10 12}: I put it through this method to get a pair that adds up to a target number such as 10.

```
static int[] getCandidatePair(int A[], int target) {
    int []pair = {0,0};
    int size = A.length;

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                if (A[i]+ A[j] == target) {
                    pair[0] = A[i];
                    pair[1]= A[j];
                }//end if
            }//end for i    
    }//end for j
    return pair;
}//end get method
```

How do I make the outputted pair (4,6) instead of the (-2,12). I'm thinking I may have to sort the array in this function too?

Comment: `int []pair` is 1d array, but you seem to need 2d array. or better create some custom class.

Comment: Is this supposed to ignore the case of `i == j`?

Comment: I think you need to return in the if statement

Comment: In this particular case returning when you find the first candidate (pair) would get you (4, 6), but that won't work in general. So for a generalized solution you would save all candidates in some collection and before returning the result you would sort that collection based on what your rules for best (or desired) solution are. Or you could use your "decision" (ordering) function inside the loops and always only keep the "better" candidate, in that way you always end the loop with the best candidate.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int[] getCandidatePair(int A[], int target) {
int []pair = {0,0};
int size = A.length;

for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if ((A[i] + A[j]) == target) {
                pair[0] = A[i];
                pair[1]= A[j];
                return pair;
            }//end if
        }//end for i    
    }//end for j
return pair;
}//end get method
```

Based on the information you provided, this might solve your problem. What was happening first was that your method wasn't returning the first pair it matched. This is because there was not a return statement in your if statement block. Hence, it missed the (4,6) pair and returned the last pair numbers which matched according to your input.